# C++ debugger ignoring breakpoints, but breaking on std::sort()

Tags: c++, gdb

I was working on a problem on Leetcode, and wanted to debug a weird looking WA. I brought my code over to VSCode as "seamlessly" as I could, hence the weird formatting for my code. For starters, my code is spitting out a completely different answer than on Leetcode. If that wasn't annoying enough, when I go to debug, my debugger ignores my breakpoints, and only breaks on std::sort(), as well as some of its header file calls. I'm using GDB.

I'm aware that my solution sucks, and I'm also aware of the far easier and more efficient solution right beneath my nose, but that isn't the focus of the post.

Here's my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    int binSearch(vector<int*> nums, int t) {
        int l = 0, r = nums.size(), m = 0;
        
            while (l < r) {
            m = floor((l+r)/2);
            if (*nums[m] > t) {
                r = m;
            } else {
                l = m+1;
            }
        }
        return r-1;
    }
    
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int*> copy;
        int ans[2];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            copy.push_back(&nums[i]);
        }
        
        sort(copy.begin(), copy.end(), [](int* a, int* b) { return *a < *b; });
        for (auto j : copy) {
            cout << *j;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < copy.size(); i++) {
            int index = binSearch(copy, target - *copy[i]);
            if (index < 0) { continue; }
            if (nums[index] == target - *copy[i]) {
                ans[0] = distance(&nums[0], copy[i]);
                ans[1] = distance(&nums[0], copy[index]);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        vector<int> out(ans, ans+2);
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> v{0,4,3,0};
    Solution sol;

    vector<int> ans = sol.twoSum(v, 0);

    cout << ans[0] << endl << ans[1];

    return 0;
}

Leetcode Output: [752,24624] //this is probably the random values assigned to an uninitialised arr
VSCode Output: 0
```

Here's my C++ launch task:

```
{
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "targetArchitecture": "x86_64",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            /*"logging": {
                "moduleLoad": true,
                "programOutput": true,
                "trace": true,
                "traceResponse": true,
                "engineLogging": true
            },*/
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        },
```

Additionally, the path to the file has no non-ASCII characters, and I did compile with -g

Comment: Do you also have optimizations off for the debug build?

Comment: Typically, the binary search condition is `while (l <= r)`. And you are correct about the quality of this solution. So much unnecessary work. Especially with that 'copy'.

Comment: `std::floor()` returns a floating point type. You're converting your integer division to a double and back to an integer. You need to care about the sloppiness of the code and not just your debugger. Why make the work harder for yourself? Without a link to the problem, one can only assume what you're attempting. It looks like you're attempting to find two elements that sum to a given value? Is it always `0`? `std::distance()` is for iterators; when you have indices you can just do the arithmetic.

Comment: @sweenish Again, I know the answer is unnecessary. I wanted to do something that would make me work with pointers and references more, since I want to sharpen those skills. My binary search is modified to prioritise the rightmost element in the event of duplicates, and it seems to work fine. Regardless, that isn't the point of my post. My issue is with my debugger not breaking. I'll figure that out first, then I'll fix the code itself.

Comment: The first fix would be to include what you use, and not implementation-specific headers. If you want to work with pointers and references, find a problem that needs them. Don't shoehorn them where they don't belong.

Comment: And if you want the debugger fixed, providing your `tasks.json` would be a great start. It helps to see how the binary is built. Along with the compiler being used and its version and how it was installed. It looks like g++ via minGW, but how was that installed? If it wasn't via MSYS2, I would recommend going back and doing it that way.

Comment: @sweenish I posted my first comment before I saw your second. This is just the Leetcode 1 TwoSum problem. I'm looking for 2 numbers that sum to a target. My tactic is to iterate through a sorted copy of the array, binary searching for a match. It isn't always zero. I'm using std::distance() to find the index of the answers in the unsorted array. Regardless, I really just want to get my debugger working. I'm not here to get ragged on over some subpar code. I know it's bad. That's why I'm working to improve.

Comment: And I'm saying that if you know the code is bad, fix it. Debugging this code is putting lipstick on a pig. You said you are aware of the better solution. Implement that, and debug it if necessary. As it stands you don't provide any information that will get you help with the debugger. The only thing I see is that it doesn't quite look like you're using what VS Code provides out of the box. You don't show where you're dropping breakpoints, you don't show the unexpected output. What you gave us is your code. So that's what I'm commenting on.

Comment: `if (nums[index] == target - *copy[i])` doesn't look right. The value of `index` is particular to the `copy` vector, and has no relation to the `nums` vector because the copy has been sorted.

Comment: @paddy Totally right. I meant to verify the integrity of copy[index], then use the line 2 later to convert the index from the copy index to the nums index. Thank you.

Comment: @paddy Submitted with your edit and it passed. Thank you.